# How to handle this error in react-native test "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I got this error when I wanted to test my component by jest
below you is my .babelrc config

```
{
    "presets": [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": "commonjs" }], "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

here is my github repository
https://github.com/shayanzd20/movie

Answer (score 0):

You may have named your test file `something.js` instead of `something.jsx`.  `.js` files do not support component bracket syntax and will throw this error.

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't work

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't fix your issue, but your test won't work without it, I recommend you change the extension